# MSCV give an error about "unrecognized source file type..." although I didn't specify any arguments

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

I'm having a problem about MSVC. When I try run Developer command prompt and type `cl`, it give me this error:

```
Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.29.30137 for x86
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

cl : Command line warning D9024 : unrecognized source file type 'C:\Program', object file assumed
cl : Command line warning D9024 : unrecognized source file type 'Files', object file assumed
cl : Command line warning D9024 : unrecognized source file type '(x86)\Microsoft', object file assumed
cl : Command line warning D9024 : unrecognized source file type 'Visual', object file assumed
cl : Command line warning D9024 : unrecognized source file type 'Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\bin\Hostx86\x86\cl.exe', object file assumed
Microsoft (R) Incremental Linker Version 14.29.30137.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

/out:Program.exe
C:\Program
Files
(x86)\Microsoft
Visual
Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\bin\Hostx86\x86\cl.exe
LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'Program.exe'
```

I'm not sure what happening. I try reinstalling Visual Studio and repairing it yet still not working. I try to do some research to find the solutions, none found.

Comment: "When I try run Developer command prompt and type cl" Why are you doing this? What do you want to accomplish? `cl` needs arguments, running it with no arguments makes no sense.

Comment: I just testing if msvc compiler work after installing vs

Comment: I can't reproduce this on 19.29.30037. I get _usage: cl [ option... ] filename... [ /link linkoption... ]_

Comment: @chris yeah that is what it supposed to do

Comment: I get the same output if I actually run `cl C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\bin\Hostx86\x86\cl.exe` instead of just `cl`. Are you sure that's not what's actually being run?

Comment: @chris yeah I just run `cl` only

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check if you have a user or system environment variable called either `CL` or `_CL_` defined.

Assuming Windows 10, go to *Start* → *Settings* → *System* → *About* → click on the *Advanced system settings* link, then in the *System Properties* dialog, on the *Advanced* tab, click the *Environment Variables…* button to see and check in both lists there.

As documented by Microsoft on [CL environment variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/cl-environment-variables), defining such variables will interfere with the CL tool by prepending or appending the specified arguments to the command line. Sometimes, setting a `CL` or `_CL_` variable before invoking MSBuild is useful for injecting preprocessor macros (using the [`/D` option](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/d-preprocessor-definitions)) to alter some aspect of the compilation, for example.

Normally, there should be no such variables in the environment. Perhaps you have one of those variables globally set to the path of `cl.exe`, this is wrong. So, just delete the variable(s).

Comment: Thanks! Deleting the variable solve this :)